# Rmarkdown toc_float not highlighting at right section, possible mathjax connection

Tags: html, r-markdown, mathjax, tableofcontents

I'm doing a write-up in Rmarkdown (knitting as HTML previewing in window) with a lot of MathJax equations. I'm using `toc_float`, but I'm having an issue with the table of contents highlighting the wrong section at parts of the page. This is my set-up for my document:

`---
title: "Title"
author: "Author"
date: "Date"
output:
  html_document:
    theme: "flatly"
    keep_md: true
    toc: true
    toc_depth: 5
    toc_float:
      collapsed: false
---`

The entire document renders without error, and if I click on the hyperlinks in the table of contents, everything works perfectly (aligned right at the start of each section).

When I knit the document, there's an initial delay where my MathJax code is small, and then after a few seconds, it renders to normal size. It appears that the table of contents highlighting its current section is in the right place when the MathJax code is small, but once the MathJax code renders to normal size, the highlighting is off.

I'm guessing what's going on is `toc_float` assigns the highlighting based on where I am on the page when the MathJax code is small. Any suggestions on how to fix this (some modification to `toc_float`, a different implementation of MathJax, or some other workaround)?

Comment: Please add a live sample, e.g. a link to a page that exhibits the problem.

Comment: Here's a draft of what I've got so far: https://gjkoplik.github.io/spectral_clustering/

In particular note the highlighting on the "Putting It All Together" Section

Comment: I think your guess is correct. You'll need to figure out how to tell the TOC to "refresh" its logic.